# PIL Image.save results in incorrect pixel mapping

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read data from a JPEG using pillow, then save it to a new image, however, when I read the data from the newly saved image, it does not correspond to the data from the original!

here is the script:

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open("original.jpg")
data1 = list(im1.getdata())

newim = Image.new("RGB", im1.size)
newim.putdata(data1)
newim.save("new.jpg")

im2 = Image.open("new.jpg")
data2 = list(im2.getdata())

for i in range(10):
    print data1[i], data2[i]
```

After running that, the output is:

```
(113, 191, 255) (114, 189, 254)
(113, 191, 255) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(112, 190, 254) (114, 189, 254)
(113, 191, 255) (115, 190, 255)
(113, 191, 253) (115, 190, 255)
```

Shouldn't these values be identical?

I am using python 2.7.9, with pillow 2.7.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Shouldn't these values be identical?"
No. JPEG is a [lossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format - which means that at save time, the Jpeg encoding library can change the actual values in the pixels - which can vary due to many factors - desired jpeg quality being one of them.

If you save the new image as a ".png" file, though - and compare it later with what is read from the original jpeg image, the values should be identical:
reading jpeg with the same library should be deterministic (and so should png images)